# File size difference between XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdftex, file-size

When working with MacTeX 2010, I noticed that XeLaTeX generates files considerably smaller than pdfLaTeX on the same input.

Even with the small example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

pdfLaTeX generates a pdf-file around 10KB, while XeLaTeX produces one around 2KB. With larger projects, I was still able to reduce the size by a factor of 2 with no noticable changes in the output.

Does anyone know what causes the difference in the file size?

Comment: The discussion on [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9983/file-size-savings) may be relevant.

Comment: As mentioned in the thread posted by @ESultanik: The compiler version is important. Which version of `pdflatex` and `xelatex` are you using? They print its version onto the terminal and into the log file. I don't know which version come with MacTeX 2010.

Comment: The versions are `pdflatex`: 3.1415926-1.40.11; `xelatex`: 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4.

Answer (score 16):

For you minimal example it is the font format which makes the difference. This can be seen by comparing the PDFs in an editor which supports binary (like vim).

Also `pdffonts` is helpful:

```
xelatex: (1874 bytes compressed, 2444 bytes uncompressed)
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZOJBFE+CMR10                         Type 1C           yes yes no       6  0


pdflatex: (10785 bytes compressed, 11677 bytes uncompressed)
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
SLFVOY+CMR10                         Type 1            yes yes no       2  0
```

The [`pdffonts` manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdffonts) states that "Type 1C" is the [Compact Font Format (CFF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Compact_Font_Format) which is as the name says more compact.

> With larger projects, I was still able to reduce the size by a factor of 2 with no noticeable changes in the output.

It depends on what font you are using and what you mean with "larger". I recently figured out that changing to T1 increase a 9-page manual (`ydoc` package) from 217K to 323K. Changing to the `libertine` font makes 482K out of it. See 
[How to create small PDF files for the Internet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2198/2975) for tips on how to reduce the file size.

Comment: I was too slow to post an answer so I just add that in some cases, pdfLaTeX output could be smaller than XeTeX as described here: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/tMRBZxjM24pXVoAkUcZU

If you want to achieve the smallest possible size, it is also worth trying latex+dvips+ps2pdf.