# XeLaTeX output prints fine, pdfLaTeX print fails

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdf

I have generated two PDF files from the same source, one via XeLaTeX and the other via pdfLaTeX. The pdfLaTeX file is larger (as already noted in [File size difference between XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14102/file-size-difference-between-xelatex-and-pdflatex)). The PDF generated from pdfLaTeX fails to print using a canon iR-ADV 4225 copier/printer. I plan to file this as a bug with canon but I can't even find a way to identify how these files are different (other than size). Looking at the fonts included in the PDF file, they appear as the same list according to Adobe Reader. From the earlier discussion, I suspect the compact fonts explain the file size different but can't determine why this would create a failure at the printer. If I remove the mathdesign bitstream font lines then both files print fine via the printer. Is there something else I can try?

Added in edit:
A minimal test case is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

I have noticed this error with any files I compile using pdfLaTeX whereas re-compling with XeLaTeX works fine. I've adjusted my workflow, but still curious why this matters.

The compiled files (source and two output PDFs are available at the following link if interested):

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c2chzk7ijcl65nk/AABvbsBuGinrtkBYmtHRnIhAa?dl=0

Other (possibly relevant) details:
Mac OSX 10.11.1
Canon ir-ADV 4225 driver version 10.7.0

Comment: Welcome! Note that questions should be self-contained so that they are useful to many users. They shouldn't depend on external links. Moreover, many readers will be extremely reluctant to download arbitrary files from unknown sources. Can you create a small example document demonstrating the problem? If not, perhaps it is just the size which is the problem? Limited memory in the printer and a failure to spool stuff in a sufficiently controlled way?

Comment: Size seems to not be a factor, I've had the minimal test case fail, regular sized PDFs (30k or so) fail, and always the XeLaTeX version prints fine. The pdfLaTeX version only fails on a specific printer driver (canon irADV 4225) but prints fine to a generic PS printer. Not sure what pdfLaTeX could possibly be doing that makes it's files different. I suspect the canon driver, but would like TeX expert advice if there is any before I scold them for a bad driver.

Comment: Which version of MacTeX? Which versions of `pdflatex` and `xelatex`?

Comment: XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) and pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)

Comment: You probably don't want to use `T1` with XeLaTeX. It isn't wrong, but it isn't usually what you need. (This is off-topic because I have no idea why your PDF won't print, but thought I'd mention it.)

Comment: Have you tried LuaTeX? Would be interesting to know whether that works.

Comment: I compiled with LuaLaTeX and see that the file size is comparable to pdfLaTeX (about 130 bytes smaller). I will try printing next time I have access.

Comment: It might be helpful because it is also using non-compact fonts, so if that's the issue, it should scupper that one, too. Of course, there could be some other common feature... and it isn't clear why the printer would dislike only some of these fonts. If you need a workaround, printing the PDF as an image (from Adobe Reader) often works when saner methods fail.

Comment: Interestingly, considering your problem (which I cannot reproduce with the above file), it is arguable that you should not use `mathdesign` with `xelatex` or `lualatex` at all since `mathdesign.sty` ends with `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontspec}`....

Comment: @cfr well it is wrong really (as all hyphenation will be incorrect for words with non-ascii characters) pdftex loads T1 based hyphenation tables into the format. xetex (in its default setup on texlive) only loads unicode based hyphenation tables.

Comment: @jon Surely not quite that?!

Comment: @jon You mean `fontenc`, not `fontspec`, right?

Comment: @Sverre -- Oops, yes!

Comment: @cfr -- Oops, yes! I meant `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}`...